# How can I include inline JS in my karma.conf.js?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular app that defines a constant within the ASP.NET Razor view like this:

```
<script>angular.module("app").constant("versionNumber", "@ViewBag.VersionNumber");</script>
```

How can I include something similar to this snippet in my `karma.conf.js`? I would just set the version number to an arbitrary static value.

Comment: You want to include an angular module in karma? I'm not sure what you are wanting. The karma.config.js is just a js page so you can put whatever js you want in it.

Comment: @MatthewGreen The `karma.config.js` has a `files` property that you can use to specify the files of your app, but the code above exists in a razor view. So I was wondering if instead of specifying a file if I could fake it out by just including this line of code inline somehow.

Comment: After I posted this question, I just added a new file that has the fake version number in it and included that in the `karma.conf.js` "files" property and excluded it from the actual app code and that seems to work. I'll leave this question here though in case there's a feature of karma that I didn't know about that would be useful for this.